# Can't fix broken packages through terminal or synaptic on 16.10

Tags: apt, package-management, wine, dpkg, dependencies

So, I'm in a bit of a predicament it seems. I was updating/reinstalling winebottler, with `sudo apt-get install wine-staging`, and then I got this error message.

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 wine-staging : Depends: wine-staging-i386 (= 1.9.22~ubuntu16.10.1)
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

I then try to solve this by typing every single common terminal command that I found, such as `sudo apt-get install -f`, and commands of the sort. install -f just came up with no errors; and so I went into synaptic to try and install wine. I tried installing wine-staging, and as expected, I get an error about broken packages. I go into the menu, and click edit->fix broken packages. I then get this error:

```
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
E: Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages.
E: Unable to correct dependencies
E: Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages.
E: Unable to correct dependencies
```

Here I am now, trying to find a way to fix this, after it has become an issue in many areas. I am also having problems with valve's shitty steam build, and was told to install steam from `sudo apt-get install steam`. I cannot due so, as an error along the same lines as the wine error. I would love any help.

Requested Outputs:

1. [`sudo apt-get -o Debug::pkgProblemResolver=yes install wine`](http://pastebin.com/Wr2pmxDQ)
2. [`apt-cache policy libgl1-mesa-glx:amd64 libwayland-egl1-mesa:amd64 mpv:amd64 smplayer:amd64 smplayer-themes:amd64 libsdl2-2.0-0:amd64 smplayer-l10n:amd64 libwayland-egl1-mesa:i386 libgtk-3-0:i386 libglu1-mesa:i386 libgtk-3-0:amd64 libgl1-mesa-glx:amd64 wine-staging-i386:i386 wine-staging:amd64 libgl1-mesa-glx:amd64 libglapi-mesa:amd64 libgles2-mesa:amd64 libosmesa6:amd64 libosmesa6:i386 wine-staging:amd64`](http://pastebin.com/qKPfEjW8)

EDIT: After the lovely help from user.dz below, I fixed this by opening software-properties-gtk , disabling ppa.launchpad.net/oibaf/gallium-nine/ubuntu PPA , and then running `sudo apt update` and then `sudo apt install wine-staging`.

Comment: Do you need `wine-staging` to run `steam`? Could add the output of `sudo apt-get -o Debug::pkgProblemResolver=yes install wine`

Comment: Choose `Fix broken packages` in Synaptic more than once, and that should fix the problem. Report back.

Comment: @user.dz I get the same error I got before; `The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 wine-staging : Depends: wine-staging-i386 (= 1.9.22~ubuntu16.10.1)
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
`. @heynnema That didn't work.  EDIT: I realized @user.dz you probably want the full output, so I put it in a pastebin here http://pastebin.com/Wr2pmxDQ

Comment: You have a conflict with some packages  versions from a PPA. you may need to purge it. Could you post the output of `apt-cache policy libgl1-mesa-glx:amd64 libwayland-egl1-mesa:amd64 mpv:amd64 smplayer:amd64 smplayer-themes:amd64 libsdl2-2.0-0:amd64 smplayer-l10n:amd64 libwayland-egl1-mesa:i386 libgtk-3-0:i386 libglu1-mesa:i386 libgtk-3-0:amd64 libgl1-mesa-glx:amd64 wine-staging-i386:i386 wine-staging:amd64 libgl1-mesa-glx:amd64 libglapi-mesa:amd64 libgles2-mesa:amd64 libosmesa6:amd64 libosmesa6:i386 wine-staging:amd64`

Comment: Here you go; http://pastebin.com/qKPfEjW8 @user.dz

Comment: Open `software-properties-gtk` ,  Disable http://ppa.launchpad.net/oibaf/gallium-nine/ubuntu PPA , then `sudo apt update; sudo apt install wine-staging`

Comment: So far this works! And it didn't even clear my previous data/require a purge! Thanks a ton @user.dz.

Comment: @Phoen1x74 , Could you take some time to review my answer then flag it as accepted (see check sign to its left) if it is fine. If you are generous, :) vote it up. See how this site works >>> [about] <<<

Answer (score 0):

Usually, I flag similar question as duplicate of [How do I resolve unmet dependencies after adding a PPA?](https://askubuntu.com/q/140246/26246) . But that a quiet long post, that may may give you the exact answer or explain what you are facing.

1. We checked the conflict using `sudo apt-get -o Debug::pkgProblemResolver=yes install wine`

   Most of those packages are from same source archive [mesa](http://packages.ubuntu.com/source/yakkety/mesa) which is a part of the graphics stack. They should have same version in the system. Currently `12.0.3-1ubuntu2` for yakkety.

   As you can see a higher version `13.1+gallium-nine~git1611030800.078245~gd~y` take priority for some of them, and that created the issue in the first place.
2. We looked into

   `apt-cache policy libgl1-mesa-glx:amd64 libwayland-egl1-mesa:amd64 mpv:amd64 smplayer:amd64 smplayer-themes:amd64 libsdl2-2.0-0:amd64 smplayer-l10n:amd64 libwayland-egl1-mesa:i386 libgtk-3-0:i386 libglu1-mesa:i386 libgtk-3-0:amd64 libgl1-mesa-glx:amd64 wine-staging-i386:i386 wine-staging:amd64 libgl1-mesa-glx:amd64 libglapi-mesa:amd64 libgles2-mesa:amd64 libosmesa6:amd64 libosmesa6:i386 wine-staging:amd6`

   To check:

   - from where they come, to disable that repository.
   - if that some package installed with that version, to downgrade them or purge ppa completely as last solution.
   - version of both arch `amd64` `i386 of same package, because most packages have a rule to break if not same version is installed for both.

So non was installed with `13.1+gallium-nine~git1611030800.078245~gd~y` for the interesting packages, we just disable PPA.

1. Open `software-properties-gtk`
2. Disable `ppa.launchpad.net/oibaf/gallium-nine/ubuntu` PPA
3. Update packages list `sudo apt update`
4. Install wine `sudo apt install wine-staging`